# Nginx configuration difficulty

Tags: php, url, nginx, routes

Here is how my nginx setting looks

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```

When I go to url `mydomain.com/something.php?arg1=2` it looks for `something.php` in root, and returns back `file not found message`.

But what I need is, if there is no .php file in root matching current route then use current url as index.php's arguments like `index.php/something.php?arg1=2`.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Because your version looks for `index.php/something.php` and for this to work `index.php` has to be a directory.